# Linq to Entities: getting data with no relation (NOT IN)

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to figure out the way to get all records from a table that have a specific column value AND that are NOT into a relational (many to many) table.
Here's the model view:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcCzZ.png

I need all "testaction" with UserGroups_ID X, which can be done with:

```
from ta in qasEntities.TestActions
where ta.UserGroups_ID.Equals(selectedUsergroupsId)
select ta
```

How can I add a clause which would state: and where testaction has no relation to testcase

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Any()` to see if there are any records.

Something like this:

```
from ta in qasEntities.TestActions
where ta.UserGroups_ID.Equals(selectedUsergroupsId) && 
      !qasEntities.TestCase.Any(x => x.UserGroups_ID.Equals(ta.UserGroups_ID)
select ta
```

What this does is that it will check if there are any TestCases with the given `UserGroups_ID` and since there's a `!` in front, it will say "Where there aren't any TestCases with `UserGroups_ID` `XXX`".

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's exactly it. However I have a compilation error for `var testactionList = (from ta in qasEntities.TestActions
where ta.UserGroups_ID.Equals(selectedUsergroupsId) && !qasEntities.TestCases.Any(x => x.UserGroups_ID.Equals(ta.UserGroups_ID))
select ta).ToList();` : `Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.`
If I add .ToList(), I then get the error where I assign the source to a webGrid.
Thanks

Comment: What I did is:
`(from ta in qasEntities.TestActions
where ta.UserGroups_ID == selectedUsergroupsId && !qasEntities.TestCases.Any(x => x.UserGroups_ID == ta.UserGroups_ID)
select new { ID = ta.ID, Command = ta.Command, Argument1 = ta.Argument1, Argument2 = ta.Argument2, IsActive = ta.IsActive, IsDeleted = ta.IsDeleted }).ToList();` which works just fine.

Comment: Perfect! Glad I could be of service.